# How to center align the inner division vertically inside the outer division

Tags: html, css

Assume there is an inner division with id=”innerDivision” and outer division has id=”outerDivision”. The outer division encloses the inner division. How to center align the inner division vertically inside the outer division?

i have tried but did not got answer please tell ma the answer

Comment: Learn about CSS flex. And please provide the code you have tried so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#outerDivision {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
}

#innerDivision {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Browser</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outerDivision">
        <div id="innerDivision">
            <span>innerDivision</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#outerDivision {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
}

#innerDivision {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Browser</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outerDivision">
        <div id="innerDivision">
            <span>innerDivision</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```